# Execute Test in MTM via Code

Tags: c#, selenium, microsoft-test-manager

I have a set of Selenium based tests in MTM which are in the form of unit tests. I'm able to run them fine if I go into MTM and tell them to run. What im wondering is if theres some sort of API I can use to kick these off?

We have a dashboard written in ASP.NET and what we really wanted is if we could have like a play button that would execute the test plan. I'm not really sure what to search for in this respect or even if its possible at all.

A possible solution is me building a test harness and using reflection to run through the DLLs but thats going to be messy.

Comment: I created a similar tool. Maybe you could give it a try.https://github.com/colutti/TestManagerHelper

Comment: Thanks for sharing Rafael. I'll be sure to take a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute tests you are managing in *MTM* using *TFS API*.
Unfortunately this *API* is very poorly documented on *MSDN*, it's realy a shame...
My hint: change to the *Visual Studio 2012* version on *MSDN* page and you will get more documentation (still way too little but better than nothing...).

Here is an example how to run all *Test Cases* that belong to a particular *Test Suite* in your *Test Plan* for a particular *Test Configuration* on a test environment of your choice:

```
string tfsUri= <tfs uri like    @"https://<your tfs>/tfs/<your collection>"      >;
string userName = <TFS user name>;
string password = <password>,
string projectName = <TFS project name>;
int planId = <test plan id>;
int suiteId = <test suite id>;
int settingsId = <test settings id>;
int configurationId = <test configuration id>;
string environmentName = <test environment you want to run the tests on>;

TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsUri), new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password));
tfsCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();

ITestManagementService testManagementService = tfsCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
ITestManagementTeamProject project = testManagementService.GetTeamProject(projectName);

//Get user name
TeamFoundationIdentity tfi = testManagementService.AuthorizedIdentity;

ITestPlan plan = project.TestPlans.Find(planId);
ITestSuiteBase suite = project.TestSuites.Find(suiteId);
ITestSettings testSettings = project.TestSettings.Find(settingsId);
ITestConfiguration testConfiguration = project.TestConfigurations.Find(configurationId);

// Unfortunately test environment name is not exactly the name you see in MTM.
// In order to get the name of your environments just call
// project.TestEnvironments.Query()
// set a breakpoint, run this code in debuger and check the names.      
ITestEnvironment testEnvironment = project.TestEnvironments.Find((from te in project.TestEnvironments.Query()
                                                                  where te.Name.ToUpper().Equals(environmentName.ToUpper())
                                                                  select te.Id).SingleOrDefault());

ITestRun testRun = plan.CreateTestRun(true);
testRun.Owner = tfi;
testRun.Controller = testEnvironment.ControllerName;
testRun.CopyTestSettings(testSettings);
testRun.TestEnvironmentId = testEnvironment.Id;
testRun.Title = "Tests started from the dashboard";

//Get test points
ITestPointCollection testpoints = plan.QueryTestPoints("SELECT * FROM TestPoint WHERE SuiteId = " + suite.Id + " and ConfigurationId = " + testConfiguration.Id);

foreach (ITestPoint tp in testpoints)
{
    testRun.AddTestPoint(tp, tfi);
}

// This call starts your tests!
testRun.Save();
```

Comment: Elena, one more question, would this start them on one of the machines set up in the MTM environment? or would this start them on the local machine?

Comment: This code starts them on the MTM environment. The example contains the call project.TestEnvironments.Find(...) and then uses the environment you get when setting the test run property: testRun.Controller = testEnvironment.ControllerName. This is the way to specify which MTM environment tests should run on.

Comment: Just to update on this. The code works perfectly! The only thing that I had trouble with was the line:

ITestPointCollection testpoints = plan.QueryTestPoints("SELECT * FROM TestPoint WHERE SuiteId = " + suite.Id + " and ConfigurationId = " + testConfiguration.Id);

It didnt return anything so I had to use this:

ITestPointCollection testpoints = plan.QueryTestPoints(string.Format("SELECT * FROM TestPoint WHERE RecursiveSuiteID = {0}",
                                                       plan.RootSuite.Id));

Thanks again Elena!

Answer (score 2):

You can run test cases with associated automation from the command line using MSTEST.exe instead of using the user interface provided by Microsoft Test Manager. This enables you to start runs automatically from a batch file.

See [Running Automated Tests from the Command Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx) and [Using MSTest from the Command Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155804.aspx)

Here's an example of how to do it:

1. Add MSTEST.EXE to your path, mine is located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE
2. Open cmd
3. Check out the list of commands available [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx), I will use /testcontainer and /test
4. /testcontainer specifies where your .dll is located
5. /test specifies which individual test case to run

My final command is

```
mstest /testcontainer:"C:\Trunk\Project\bin\x86\Debug\TestProject.dll" /test:SmokeTest
```

Comment: Link-only answers are generally frowned upon on SO. Could you pull some relevant quotes out of that article so that this answer remains helpful to future visitors, even if that link is dead?

Comment: For sure, that's no problem at all.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion JeffX i'll give it a shot and update here once im done.

Comment: I've marked Elena for the best answer id like to up vote you too for your help but unfortunately I don't have enough rep to do this.

Comment: @Jonkers, I think you can now.